# How do I learn to read the Qur'an?

Tags: quran

I don't know how to read the Quran properly. My parents can't help me in this regard. I went to a mosque to learn but after some time I left because they were teaching me with an accent and I was embarrassed as I was the oldest between small children. What should I do?

Comment: for prayer, write short surah's in your language with proper [length of vowels](http://www.falooka.com/modules_read_learn/read_learn_vowels_2.htm) with the help of roman transliteration and online recitation, accent not necessary. To learn to recite Quran, take a (**free** /paid )online course

Comment: Hi! I really appreciate that you are worry about to learn quran. Age is not matter at all so never think that you are too old to learn. You are worry about it, that's good thing. I hope some of our muslim brother or sister will guide you on right way.

Comment: Instead of online course, it's better to contact some one who can teach you.

Comment: I feel the same way, use a colour coded tajweed Quran shareef it guides you to the way of learning different gunnahs and stuff

Comment: if you wanted to do it the interesting way, "listen while you read". But first it needs you should have completed learning the letters of Arabic, and its basic grammar. Then, open the English translation of your favorite translator and play the Qur'an by your favorite reciter, alongside with sync. Then you read the verse along side listen to it. There by you can get the most of the words, their meanings and their usage too. By that you can memorize the verses too in a short span of time comparatively, without bothering much about how to read "Arabic". This is what I do. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assalam o Alikum 
I appreciate your concern

Age is NO limitation and  Be proud  that  you are among those blessed one  who  desire to learn to recite and Understand Holy Book. 
I suggest that you download Audios of small Sura of Holy book,  download Holy Quran.  Now  Listen  and follow

Since I am like million other Muslim by Birth and live where Arabic  is very familiar , though not Mother Tongue , so  may not be able to understand exactly the problems being faced.

[image]
Check  this  ,  if this could be of some help.

http://openitpak.wordpress.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=280&action=edit&message=6&postpost=v2
Else I can email each Sura separately .

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, be glad because your question is a sign of *iman* (faith). There are millions of Muslims who couldn't be bothered about being able to read Allah's message to humanity.

Secondly, it's best to find someone local to teach you. It doesn't have to be a professional imam or Qur'an teacher, but even just someone above average in your masjid or your community. Someone who knows the proper pronunciation and the basic rules of *tajwid* (the rules of recitation), and who can spare a few hours a week to teach you. Once you graduate from them, you can seek out higher level help.

If you live in a place where there is no such person, then there are a number of online institutes who can help you for a nominal fee. I've heard good things about Studio Arabiya.

Finally, there is no reason to be embarrassed even if you are in a class with young children. There are people in their 60s and 70s learning to read Qur'an for the first time. When it comes to seeking knowledge, there is no shyness.