# How should I practise Arabic in order to read Quran?

Tags: arabic, reading-quran, tajweed

Arabic is not like western languages, say Spanish, which is not difficult if you have learned all the consonants and vowels, because you can spell and speak all the letter combinations correctly by yourself. But I find the Arabic language is a bit different, although you have learned all the consonants and vowels, you still can not spell and pronounce the letter combinations correctly, as the radio teaches you.   For example, the Arabic symbol vowel ( َ ) changes a bit when is spelled together with the consonants like خ ر ص ض ط ظ ق ع و ی，  In these letter combinations, the symbol vowel (  َ ) sounds like 'u' in the word 'but', but if combined with the other consonants, the symbol vowel (  َ ) sounds close to 'e' in the word 'bed'. So I can't use the common rule to read them but remember and mimic them one by one.

Comment: Sounds like you need an Arabic teacher. See also: "[How do I learn to read the Qur'an?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/11406/9123)". Tip: Watch tutorials in youtube and search for sites which teach the rules and how to pronounce them perfectly. There are plenty online. Search well. Next time ,if you have any **specific** question (if you get stuck somewhere) make sure you ask with the [tag:arabic] tag.

Comment: Well yes in Arabic there are letters (29/30) and tones (4 if the neutral tone is calculated)  so you'll have to learn how each letter would be read according the tone. But while the combination of some letters may change the tone in other languages this isn't the case as far as i can tell in Arabic! Let take your example spanish: "ll" is different then "l" or in english "s" or "h" separated are different then "sh" or as far as i can say many spanish speakers would have problems with the "sp" at the beginning of a word which is very common in german. So you may have to learn and practice this!

Comment: you can get an account in [speaky](https://www.speaky.com/) i will see if i can help you practicing arabic !

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Hinative](https://hinative.com/) app to practice arabic. There are many native speakers who would love to help you.

Also, I find [Memrise Basic Arabic](http://www.memrise.com/course/82825/learn-basic-arabic/) course very useful.

Comment: There are no native Arabic speakers, people speak in various dialects, these dialects are spin offs from the Arabic langauge, if you use the Arabic that is in the Quran to speak to a modern day Arab, he will not understand you

Comment: Well, that's true.